# React Server Side rendered form clears input after React components initialize

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that's fully Reactified, and uses server side rendering to display the page immediately rather than after the React script loads.

The problem is that if the user starts typing any information into the form, as soon as React loads and rebuilds the form, that input is erased. What is the proper way to prevent this from happening without having to jump through too many hoops?

Ideally I'd like the input to be kept and then stored in the React state.

Comment: Your form should not be taking that long to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `value` attribute in your form components? If so, this components considered [*controlled components*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), which makes them reflect the value stored inside the component. The moment React initialise component on the DOM element the value of element resets.

There are two workarounds:

1. Do not use controlled components and make data-binding by yourself. How to do that is described in [React Forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) documentation.
2. Make your form disabled by default and enable it after React fully initialised.

Answer (score 0):

[React version 16.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.0.0) added an api `ReactDOM.hydrate` to be used instead of `ReactDOM.render` when doing server side rendering. Replacing render with hydrate solved this issue for me.